# Undefined method "delete" on redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I'm authenticating using the [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/doc/authorization.md) gem trying to redirect the user via the auth url returns the error

`"undefined method 'delete' for #<Addressable::URI:0x0000000d8c1128>"`

For reasons I'm not entirely aware of. Here's my code:

```
class UserFormsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  before_action :set_user_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :g_auth_user

  # GET /user_forms
  def index
    @user_forms = UserForm.all
    redirect_to @auth_url
  end

[...]

  def g_auth_user
    credentials = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
      client_id: "506139056270-iu34antv0ebbouo332p55gem8vj5uj9b.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      client_secret: "CNc0okSHqFBsmLSeZgzDhyHJ",
      scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/",
      ],
      redirect_uri: user_forms_url)
    @auth_url = credentials.authorization_uri
  end

[...]
```

Comment: Are you sure that error's being triggered in this code and not your view? Check the back-trace more carefully.

Comment: @tadman forgive my inexperience, but I'm not sure what you mean or expect me to find? Could you elaborate?

Comment: That error is just one line of the complete message. Normally Ruby will try and direct you through the chain of events that lead to it. This is called a backtrace or "stack trace" in other languages. The last line of your code in that list is where you start looking for problems. I don't see any calls to `delete` in your code here, so it's presumably made elsewhere, like in the view.

Comment: @tadman Ah, I see what you mean now. No, I've checked through the stack trace in the error window and found nothing. All erroneous calls are to rails default files. The view also seems fine- it's practically the same as when first scaffolded and deleting `redirect_to @auth_url` in the controller removes the error.

Comment: Does `redirect_to @auth_url.to_s` resolve the issue?

Comment: @tadman It does indeed. Thank you very much! It leads to other errors, but those are unrelated and fixable on my part. If you'd like to submit that as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the URI structure returned by that method is incompatible with `redirec_to` so you should be able to fix it by converting it to a string:

```
redirect_to @auth_url.to_s
```